# iterate text file in php, multiple lines as one iteration or sub iterate perhaps

Tags: php, loops

I am trying to convert a text based accounting file to an array using php. The structure of each verification line is the following:

```
#VER A 14 20160715 "mats" 20161016
{
#TRANS 1930 {} -3000.00 20160715 "mats"
#TRANS 2893 {} 3000.00 20160715 "mats"
}
#VER A 15 20160719 "Mats" 20161016
{
#TRANS 1930 {} -20000.00 20160719 "Mats"
#TRANS 2893 {} 20000.00 20160719 "Mats"
}
```

So I wan't to iterate each line starting with #VER and then subiterate the lines starting with #TRANS between the curly braces {}. Having problems with the subiterate part. My goal is an array such as below (hope there are no errors...)

```
Array
(
[#VER] => Array
    (
        [A14] => Array
            (
                [verdatum] => 20160714
                [vertext] => mats
                [trans] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [transaccount] => 1930
                                [transamount] => -3000.00
                                [transdate] => 20160715
                                [transtext] => mats
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [transaccount] => 2893
                                [transamount] => 3000.00
                                [transdate] => 20160715
                                [transtext] => mats
                            )

                    )   
            )
        [A15] => Array
            (
                [verdatum] => 20160719
                [vertext] => Mats
                [trans] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [transaccount] => 1930
                                [transamount] => -20000.00
                                [transdate] => 20160719
                                [transtext] => Mats
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [transaccount] => 2893
                                [transamount] => 20000.00
                                [transdate] => 20160719
                                [transtext] => Mats
                            )

                    )   
            )
    )

)
```

Code so far:

```
foreach($contentsarray as $line_value)
{

    if (substr($line_value,0,4)=="#VER") {
        list($ver, $serie, $vernr, $verdatum, $vertext, $verregdatum, $versign) = str_getcsv($line_value, ' ');
        $verif[$ver][$serie.$vernr]['verdatum']= $verdatum;
        $verif[$ver][$serie.$vernr]['vertext']= $vertext;

    WHAT TO DO HERE?

    }

}
```

Any guidance much appreciated.

Comment: There are many ways you can do this, but you have to start by deciding what the end result has to be. We can see a hint of that in your code, but that's far from complete. Then you can, for instance, parse it line by line, by keeping track of the state you're in, but you could also have a line pointer and use the structure of your code to hold the state. I think you intended to do the latter.

Comment: Please provide specifics, input, desired output and the current output you are getting.

Comment: Many thanks so far. Added desired output above.

Comment: The space between `A 15` or `A 14` to make an array key `A15` or `A14` will make things very difficult to produce your desired output.

Comment: Is there a way to iterate the rows in segments/rowchunks? In words select all rows from #Ver until next instance of #Ver, and the I can work on from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for regular expressions:

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents($filePath);
if( preg_match_all('/^#VER(.*)\n{\n((^#TRANS.*\n)+)}/m', $fileContent, $matches) ){
   foreach($matches[0] as $i=>$match){
      echo 'VER    : '.$matches[1][$i].PHP_EOL;
      echo 'TRANSes: '.$matches[2][$i].PHP_EOL;
   }
}
```

**UPDATE** for desired output:

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents($filePath);
if( preg_match_all('/^#VER(.*)\n{\n((^#TRANS.*\n)+)}/m', $fileContent, $matches) ){
   foreach($matches[0] as $i=>$match){
      echo 'VER:'.$matches[1][$i].PHP_EOL;
      if( preg_match_all('/^#TRANS (\d+) {} (-?\d+\.\d+) (\d{8}) "(.*)"/m', $matches[2][$i], $matches2) ){
         foreach($matches2[0] as $j=>$match2){
            $trans = array( 'account' => $matches2[1][$j]
                          , 'amount'  => $matches2[2][$j]
                          , 'date'    => $matches2[3][$j]
                          , 'text'    => $matches2[4][$j]
                          );
            print_r($trans);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sal. Seems interesting. Please see answer above from me where I tried your solution with some follow up question.

Comment: Very good solution, many thanks! See however my new answer where I describe a slight problem.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Sals solution. Seems interesting. Trying to build on it but get a strange output. This code:

```
if( preg_match_all('/^#VER(.*)\n{\n((^#TRANS.*\n)+)}/m', $fileContent,     $matches) ){
       foreach($matches[0] as $i=>$match){
          echo 'VER    : '.$matches[1][$i].PHP_EOL; echo "</br>";
          foreach($matches[2] as $x=>$match2){
            echo 'TRANS: '.$matches[2][$x].PHP_EOL; echo "</br>";
          }
       }
    }
```

Generates:

```
VER : A 14 20160715 "mats" 20161016 
TRANS: #TRANS 1930 {} -3000.00 20160715 "mats" #TRANS 2893 {} 3000.00 20160715 "mats" 
TRANS: #TRANS 1930 {} -20000.00 20160719 "Mats" #TRANS 2893 {} 20000.00  20160719 "Mats" 

VER : A 15 20160719 "Mats" 20161016 
TRANS: #TRANS 1930 {} -3000.00 20160715 "mats" #TRANS 2893 {} 3000.00 20160715 "mats" 
TRANS: #TRANS 1930 {} -20000.00 20160719 "Mats" #TRANS 2893 {} 20000.00 20160719 "Mats"
```

Was hoping to get below:

```
VER : A 14 20160715 "mats" 20161016 
TRANS: #TRANS 1930 {} -3000.00 20160715 "mats" 
TRANS: #TRANS 2893 {} 3000.00 20160715 "mats" 
VER : A 15 20160719 "Mats" 20161016 
TRANS: #TRANS 1930 {} -20000.00 20160719 "Mats" 
TRANS: #TRANS 2893 {} 20000.00  20160719 "Mats"
```

Comment: You can explode and substring the second group, however, with another regex will be pretty easy. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution from Sal seems to be giving a working solution. Changed the code to below to build my desired array. A slight problem is that the below works fine when $fileContent is a string stored in the script, but when changing to an uploaded file the code doesn't output an array. Any thoughts on what this could be due to? Googled, perhaps trailing whitespace stopping the code?

```
$fileContent = iconv('CP437','UTF-8', file_get_contents($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']));
    if( preg_match_all('/^#VER(.*)\n{\n((^#TRANS.*\n)+)}/m', $fileContent, $matches) ){
       foreach($matches[0] as $i=>$match){
            list($ver, $serie, $vernr, $verdatum, $vertext, $verregdatum, $versign) = str_getcsv($matches[1][$i].PHP_EOL, ' ');
            $verif[$ver][$serie.$vernr]['verdatum']= $verdatum;
            $verif[$ver][$serie.$vernr]['vertext']= $vertext;

            if( preg_match_all('/^#TRANS (\d+) {} (-?\d+\.\d+) (\d{8}) "(.*)"/m', $matches[2][$i], $matches2) ){
             foreach($matches2[0] as $j=>$match2){
                $verif[$ver][$serie.$vernr]['trans'][$j] = array( 'account' => $matches2[1][$j]
                              , 'amount'  => $matches2[2][$j]
                              , 'date'    => $matches2[3][$j]
                              , 'text'    => $matches2[4][$j]
                              );
             }
          }
       }
    print "<pre>";
    print_r($verif);
    print "</pre>";


    }
```